# Sage (Python) Math Programming, Writing an Algorithm to check for Primality

Tags: python, primes, sage, number-theory

I need to write a code in Sage for a homework problem that checks whether a random number generated between 10^7 and 10^8 is prime by dividing it by all the known primes less than or equal to 10^4. I have never programmed in Sage prior to this as a warning. This is what I have so far.

```
# This creates a function to create a random number between two numbers

def random_between(j,k):
    a=int(random()*(k-j+1))+j
    return a

# Testing that the function works, which it does, though I don't know how
# to assign a variable to it like x=random_between(10^7,10^8)

random_between(10^7,10^8)

# The list of primes less than 10^4 is given by

list_of_primes = prime_range(1,10^4)

# Want to write a function to check if prime
def check_if_prime(n):
    for n in list_of_primes:
        if n % random_between(10^7,10^8)==0:
            print 'number is prime'
        else
            print 'number is not prime'
```

What I'm wanting to do is to use determine whether the numbers in `list_of_primes` divide the random number generated from `random_between` using the `%` command and then print that `number x is a prime` or that it's not.

I do know that the command `Primes()` will check whether a number is prime or not, but we are specifically supposed to do this "naive" check primality.
If someone could help me out with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Given `n < 10^4` and `10^7 <= random_x < 10^8` then `n % random_x` is always going to be `n` because `n < random_x`. I think you meant `x = random_between(10**7, 10**8); if x % n == 0: ...`

Answer (score 0):

You're `check_if_prime` function could use some work. I've re-written below.

```
def check_if_prime(): # there's no parameter for this method since we're checking against the global var list_of_primes
    for n in list_of_primes:
        if random_between(10^7,10^8) % n == 0: # if a random number / a prime number has no remainder, the random number is not prime
            print 'number is not prime'
            return # we're done, we know it's not prime
    print 'number is prime' # we made it through all of our tests, the number might be prime
```